# Number of Columns in ggplot differs with shiny- input

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am relatively new to shiny, so i would be really thankful if someone could help me with this. I want to plot a Barplot where x depends on the input. However, if the input changes now, so does the number of columns. This way some of the information gets lost as not all columns are shown. Ideally i want as many columns as are available per Person (included sample below). I couln't find any questions concerning this.

This is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

name <- c("David", "David", "David",
          "Anna", "Anna", "Anna", "Anna", "Anna",
          "Laura", "Laura", "Laura", "Laura")
occupation <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
                "Monday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Friday","Sunday", 
                "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Saturday")
n <- c(15, 37, 104, 
       60, 2, 42, 123, 19, 
       12, 34, 27, 76)

data <- data.frame(cbind(name, occupation, n))
data$name <- as.factor(data$name)
data$occupation <- as.factor(data$occupation)
data$n <- as.integer(data$n)

ui <-  fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("nam",label="", choices = levels(data$name))
    ),
    mainPanel( plotOutput("plot"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(subset(data, name==input$nam), aes(name, n))+
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=occupation), position = "dodge")
    
  })}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Hello.  It would be helpful to see an example of your desired output.

Comment: Did you need `name %in% input$nam` instead of `name==input$nam`?

Comment: @Ben yes perfect, that was it! Thank you so much!